# leaflet get custom option from geojson marker

Tags: leaflet, marker, geojson

I am trying to get clicked geojson marker's custom options.I can do it if i create marker in map.But when i get from geojson not working.My code is :

```
function onClick(e) {
get_marker(this.options.marker_id);
//geojson.features[64].options.marker_id)  
}
```

get_marker() takes marker's custom id which i defined as a custom marker like this.

```
customMarker = L.Marker.extend({
       options: { 
          marker_id: 'Custom data!',
          name: '',
          category: '',
          information: '',
          owner: ''
       }
    });
```

and i create marker in map like this.

```
map.on('click', function(e) {   
        newMarker[i] = new customMarker (e.latlng, {
            draggable : true,
            marker_id : 'new'
        }).addTo(map);
        newMarker[i].on('click', onClick);

    newMarker[i].bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br />I am a popup.");
            //.openPopup();
    save_marker(newMarker[i]);
    //$(".bilgi").val(newMarker.getPopup().getContent());
    i++;
});
```

i can't get marker_id option in geojson point.When i set geojson.features[64].options.marker_id as a get_marker parameter it works.But i cant control which marker is clicked.Maybe i have to define geojson as a custom marker but i don't know.How can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved my problem.when i try to get geojson data i create custom marker and give marker_id and it works now.And now i think using different marker type is difficult. when you create marker in map as a user and getting geojson marker from server has to be same marker type.So using same marker type is better.

```
L.geoJson(data, {
        onEachFeature : function(feature, layer) {
            var popupContent = "marker_id = " + feature.options.marker_id;
            if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
                popupContent += feature.properties.popupContent;
            }
            layer.bindPopup(popupContent);
            layer.on('click', onClick);
        },
        pointToLayer : function(feature, latlng) {
            return new customMarker(new L.LatLng(feature.geometry.

            coordinates[1], feature.geometry.coordinates[0]), {
                marker_id : feature.options.marker_id
            });
        }
    }).addTo(map);
```